# Cannot open office documents on desktop from folder with unique permissions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, permissions

I had to setup a library with unique permissions so that a group called payroll only had access to the library and not the site:

-I removed payroll from the site permissions.
-I broke the inheritance to the library and added permission to payroll.

When I click on Excel docs, it opens in Excel web services.  When I click on the "Open in Excel" button to open Excel on my desktop, it tries to download and open it but can't.  It gives the error "Sorry, we couldn't open [file location]".
For Word and PPT files, it tries to download the files and open it too but they get the same error.  If I give read permissions to payroll at the site level all documents will open fine.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Below are some additional details:

-change permission on payroll from read to full control, however document still won't open

-tested on IE8 and 11.

Answer (score 1):

This had to be a permission issue so, I create a custom permission level and ran some tests.

In this custom permission level I only checked the following under "Site permissions":

1.Use Remote Interfaces  -  Use SOAP, Web DAV, the Client Object Model or SharePoint Designer interfaces to access the Web site.
2.Open  -  Allows users to open a Web site, list, or folder in order to access items inside that container.

I set this custom permission level to my desired group.  Afterwards, the group could access and open office documents in the folder, however they couldn't browse the site.